# Unable to instantiate service com.bump.api.BumpAPI: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bump.api.BumpAPI

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, bump

I am trying to run the sample app for the Bump API 3.0, when I try to run the application on the emulator i get the following error:

`E/AndroidRuntime(742): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to instantiate service com.bump.api.BumpAPI:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bump.api.BumpAPI`

I tried to follow the API instructions (I'm rather fresh as far as android/java/any programing goes), i added the attached .jar file to the project (build path-> add JARs), and i see the missing class inside it in the "refrences libraries" list. There's also a .so file attached, this one i only placed in "libs" folder as i'm not sure how to link it to the project besides that.

I would appreciate any help on resolving this,

Thanks a lot,

Geva Tal.

EDIT: Solved after creating a new AVD...still don't know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like everything should be working fine... I suggest cleaning your project, restarting eclipse, and perhaps creating a new AVD.

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/bump-api-android/WMGHaRqoWQA

Here's the answer. Include .so into the libs folder of your project. Their instructions page is missing this.

Comment: Apparently the solution they have given doesn't work for. Follow that thread for updates.